# BigQuery - Collapse Rows By Group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have a table of various items from different data sources. Record linkage was performed between the individual columns and the findings were stored in the table shown before. I now need to collapse the results so that for each column there is only a single value for each field. For example, I have the following table:

[image]

With the following values:

[image]

And I'm looking for the result to be the following:

```
---------------------------------------
| Row | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
---------------------------------------
|  1  |   4   | NULL  | NULL  |  NULL |
---------------------------------------
|  2  |   0   |   1   |  2    |  NULL |
---------------------------------------
|  3  |   5   |  NULL |  6    |   7   |
---------------------------------------
```

In the above it can be observed that rows 2 and 3 are collapsed because they both have a value of `1`for `col_2`. Similarly, rows 4 and 5 are collapsed because they both have a `6` in `col_3`. I tried the following but I couldn't get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
SELECT
  FIRST_VALUE(c1.col_1) OVER (PARTITION BY c1.col_1 ORDER BY 1 ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS col_1,
  FIRST_VALUE(c2.col_2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY c1.col_1 ORDER BY 1 ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS col_2,
  FIRST_VALUE(c3.col_3 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY c2.col_2 ORDER BY 1 ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS col_3,
  FIRST_VALUE(c4.col_4 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY c3.col_3 ORDER BY 1 ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS col_4,
FROM
  dataset.collapse_test  c1
LEFT JOIN
  dataset.collapse_test c2
ON
  c1.col_2 = c2.col_2
LEFT JOIN
  dataset.collapse_test c3
ON
  c2.col_2 = c3.col_2
LEFT JOIN
  dataset.collapse_test c4
ON
  c3.col_3 = c4.col_3
```

Comment: What if you added a row with 5/1/2/7?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with this query, since as @Gordon Linoff said in the comment, some rows can be problematic when more than one value matches.

Therefore, here I put my attempt that generates the values you want but also keep the old ones since is difficult to understand in some cases when to keep them, as commented before.

First of all, we create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `dataset.collapse` (
   col_1 INT64,
   col_2 INT64,
   col_3 INT64,
   col_4 INT64,
) as SELECT 4 as col_1, null as col_2, null as col_3, null as col_4 UNION ALL
     SELECT 0 as col_1, 1 as col_2, null as col_3, null as col_4 UNION ALL
     SELECT null as col_1, 1 as col_2, 2 as col_3, null as col_4 UNION ALL
     SELECT null as col_1, null as col_2, 6 as col_3, 7 as col_4 UNION ALL
     SELECT 5 as col_1, null as col_2, 6 as col_3, null as col_4
```

And then we run our solution for this case, I have used the `IFNULL` function to keep only non-null values and `INNER JOIN` as a equal value condition:

```
SELECT
   IF
    (t1.col_1 IS NULL,
      CAST(CONCAT(IFNULL(t1.col_1,
          t2.col_1)) AS INT64),
    t1.col_1) AS c1,
   IF
    (t1.col_2 IS NULL,
     CAST(CONCAT(IFNULL(t1.col_2,
         t2.col_2)) AS INT64),
    t1.col_2) AS c2,
   IF
    (t1.col_3 IS NULL,
     CAST(CONCAT(IFNULL(t1.col_3,
          t2.col_3)) AS INT64),
    t1.col_3) AS c3,
   IF
    (t1.col_4 IS NULL,
     CAST(CONCAT(IFNULL(t1.col_4,
          t2.col_4)) AS INT64),
     t1.col_4) AS c4
FROM
  `project.dataset.collapse` AS t1
INNER JOIN
  `project.dataset.collapse` AS t2
ON
  t1.col_2 = t2.col_2
  OR t1.col_1 = t2.col_1
  OR t1.col_3 = t2.col_3
  OR t1.col_4 = t2.col_4
GROUP BY
  c1,
  c2,
  c3,
  c4
```

And the solution we get is this:

[image]

In order to remove the old values, the solution would be something like:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM (previous_query)
   WHERE
     CONCAT(IFNULL(c1,
           -1),IFNULL(c2,
           -1),IFNULL(c3,
           -1),IFNULL(c4,
           -1)) 
     NOT IN (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(IFNULL(col_1,
             -1),IFNULL(col_2,
             -1),IFNULL(col_3,
             -1),IFNULL(col_4,
             -1))
        FROM
           `project.dataset.collapse`
        WHERE
           CONCAT(IFNULL(col_1,
              -1),IFNULL(col_2,
              -1),IFNULL(col_3,
              -1),IFNULL(col_4,
              -1)) = CONCAT(IFNULL(c1,
                    -1),IFNULL(c2,
                    -1),IFNULL(c3,
                    -1),IFNULL(c4,
                    -1)) ))
```

Bear in mind that this solution will also remove  `[4 null null null]` row.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! What if we didn't want the original rows in the joined result?

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to remove the values that don't appear in the first table, but with this approach the value "4 null null null" will be also deleted. I'll update the answer with my solution.